# Ошибка во второй строке, из-за этого не работает код

Tags: python, list, список

```
a = ('Али 10.03','Гюнай 12.03','Фарид 15.03')
a.append("Васиф 28.03")
del a[1]
print(a)
```

Помогите пожалуйста, очень срочно

Comment: `a = (...)` --> `a = [...]`

Comment: ошибка в 1й строке

Answer (score 4):

.append - метод питон - листов. Чтобы иметь возможность им пользоваться с а, а должен быть листом. Таким образом

```
a = ['Али 10.03','Гюнай 12.03','Фарид 15.03']
```

Первая строка вашего кода